# Is this the correct way to open a .csv file in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, file, jupyter-notebook

I've so many different ways and it is still saying file not found
I'm running the code in a Jupyter Notebook.
I'd rather run the file from wherever it is. Here is the infomation for its location

[image: breadcrumb path]

Have I generated the correct code (below is the code).

```py
import numpy
    
numpy.loadtxt(fname='C:\Desktop\swc-python\data\inflammation-01.csv', delimiter=',')
```

Also tried this but it did not work:

```py
import numpy
    
numpy.fname = ('C:\Desktop\swc-python\data\small-01.csv')
openfname = open(fname,'r')
```

Also, an you save a Jupyter notebook in the same directory as the infomation.

Comment: "Did not work" is pretty broad - what does that mean? Is there any error message thrown?

Answer (score 0):

these are some examples with pandas, and os, maybe they could help

they use slash, not backward slash (this option, or the option below)

```
# import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("C:/Users/<Insert your user>/Desktop/code/Exercise Files/us_baby_names.csv")
```

or
(option below), change the current directory,

```
# import os and pandas library
import os
import pandas as pd

# show current working directory, change it, show it again
os.getcwd()
os.chdir('C:/Users/<Insert your user>/Desktop/code/Exercise Files/')
os.getcwd()
pd.read_csv("us_baby_names.csv")
```